# React router not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We are using `react-router` like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={AnyPic}>
            <Route path="p/:photoId" component={PhotoView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0] 
);

var AnyPic = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p>Hello world</p>
        )
    }
});

var PhotoView = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <p>This is the photo view</p>
        )
    }
});
```

After including `react-router`, what used to be just `localhost:8000` started looking like `localhost:8000/#/?_k=wulhmi`. Not sure where those extra params came from.

Anyway, when trying to access `localhost:8000/#/p/XYZ` the page keeps going back to `/`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [_"What is that ?_k=ckuvup junk in the URL?"_](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#what-is-that-_kckuvup-junk-in-the-url)

Comment: what do `AnyPic` and `PhotoView` look like? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @max updated to include other components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for that is because you are not rendering your children route(s). Check out [the react router docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md#with-react-router).

If you add `this.props.children` to your `AnyPic` component everything will work:

```jsx
var AnyPic = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello world</p>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

As @robertklep pointed out in the comment, the "extra" thing in the URL is being added as The Router uses Hash History by default, you probably want to use `BrowserHistory` to do that you need to install [history module](https://github.com/rackt/history): `npm install history`
See the docs [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory).